# Tools for Building a Web Application in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, web-applications

I am trying to build a web application for a data management system. I have a year's experience in Java, basic knowledge of SQL, and very little knowledge of anything else.

I have done a lot of reading online and there seems to be endless different ways you can go about building a web app. My question is what is the easiest way for somebody with my sort of experience, and what else do I need to learn. I have been using Eclipse IDE however have now downloaded Netbeans as I am unsure which IDE would be best either.

I am currently reading up on Servlet's, JSP's and HTML and am just trying to understand what I need to learn and use to get started really as I need to have the web app ready in 8 weeks!

I have also read about GlassFish, Ajax, TomCat, Apache etc. but do not really understand how they fit in or which to use.

Comment: Spring is probably your goto for java webapplications, plus there's a LOT of documentation and tutorials out there

Comment: why was this upvoted???

Comment: "I have done a lot of reading online and there seems to be endless different ways you can go about building a web app". Correct, that's the Java platform for you. I'm sorry to say there is no answer to your question - they're all difficult when you just start out especially when you lack prerequisite knowledge and understanding. Sticking with servlets is your best bet, but I'd find it an achievement if you manage to complete on time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can try some of the following approaches:

1. Download Apache Tomcat. Try to start it up. See if you can understand anything from its sample applications.
2. For Java webapp, the minimum technologies you need to know are:  Servlets, JSP. If you need database access you also need to know about JDBC.
3. Try to google for CRUD applications (i.e. Create, Read, Update, Delete applications) that use only Servlets and JSP.